# How to create short unique id for promocode

Tags: javascript, unique

I'm trying to create short unique id for peer to peer referrals in the format of :

first name + first letter of last name + short number

What would be the best way to do this? I'm thinking of doing something with account Id to generate the short number ? Since that would be self incrementing and won't have any collisions.

Answer (score 0):

Would be better to use random numbers, no? With incremented accounID you could have a security risk.

Here is a code you could run for 100 different unique numbers:

```
var arr = []
while (//create all your unique id's in here) {
        var randomnumber = Math.ceil(Math.random()*100)
        if(arr.indexOf(randomnumber) > -1) continue;
        arr[arr.length] = randomnumber;
       // first name + first letter of last name + short number
        }
```